# Can I send emails from Apex Unit Tests?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Does Salesforce block emails from being sent by Apex unit test methods?

I have a test which passes and the `SendEmailResult` is a **success** yet I do not get the email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Every single permanent effect caused by your unit tests should be rolled back once they are completed. Any other behavior would be a bug and should be reported immediately.

Comment: I have 150 email templates, and I would like a way to generate all of them, so I can review them, is there a feature to do this on mass? or should I just write a class which calls each of them?

Comment: You should be able to whip up an anonymous script easily enough to do as much.

Comment: Indeed that's what I've done, with `setup()` and `teardown()` methods to create and then clean up the data. Is there any other way to guarantee all the data is removed at the end?

Comment: Does Transaction Control stop emails from being sent?

Comment: @Robs Yes I believe `Database.rollback` would prevent emails from being sent. What other DML are you performing?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, sorry, please could you elaborate? :)

Comment: @Robs i've had scenarios like this in the past, it's not ideal, but using existing records by querying or just pasting them in the email generation scripts has been the most effective, assuming you don't want to leave any data traces behind